# How to add or start libwebsockets with SSL in UE4 .24 (html5 ue4 from source)

Tags: ssl, unreal-engine4, centos8, dedicated-server, libwebsockets

I have nice working whole multiplatforms builds for client part but
my dedicated server don't accept https/SSL i can run it only for `http` protocol on my public server (centOS8.3) .

need to use SSL on dedicated server centos 8.3 . My host mashine is windows i use cross platform tools linux with success.

I cant rebuild libwebsockets

with BUILD.EPIC.sh from libcurl i successed only with openSSL builded but not libwebsockets. I try individual also with no success on windows.

1. Is it possible to make flags ssl ON and then i will rebuild all again with HTML5Setup.sh
2. Is it possible to do it with visual studio Project / engine .

i change this part and build engine solution with no success. To make it hardcode anyway....

```
             if (UsePlatformSSL)
             {
                 // ORIGIN  
                 // PrivateDefinitions.Add("WITH_SSL=0");
                 // AddEngineThirdPartyPrivateStaticDependencies(Target, "libWebSockets");
 
                 AddEngineThirdPartyPrivateStaticDependencies(Target, "OpenSSL", "libWebSockets", "zlib");
                 PrivateDependencyModuleNames.Add("SSL");
             }
             else
             {
                 AddEngineThirdPartyPrivateStaticDependencies(Target, "OpenSSL", "libWebSockets", "zlib");
                 PrivateDependencyModuleNames.Add("SSL");
             }
```

Please any suggestion !

Even if i rebuild libwebsockets when and how to add current domain ssl key cr and ca ?

In samo answers on similar question said : rebiuld openSSL and libwebsockets again and works. How can be without changing WITH_SSL somewhere....

Comment: question is a little unclear - is it correct that you are able to build the html5 client to use wss, but you are having trouble building the centos server to allow wss connections?

Comment: I'am not sure but i think that html5 build already have switch (from ws to wss) . I have a problem with dedicated server (sorry - i will update question) - i have warn message something like "WITH_NO_SSL"  i will post it...